# Dúvidas sobre ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript

Busquei vários conteúdos na internet, porém não tive uma resposta muito clara, e gostaria de saber porque os cursos ensinam a partir do ES6 e não ES5, ES4 etc...

Existe algo em específico no ES6 que faz ele ser estudado justamente nessa versão?

Sei que existem outras versões posteriores como ES7, ES8, ES9... mas porque não começamos estudar logo essas versões atuais ao invés de ES6?

Comment: É estudado *ES6* porque é a versão suportada por todos os navegadores e ambientes JS. O *ES7* só é suportado em parte pelo Chrome e o Ópera.

Comment: @AugustoVasques cuidado com a afirmação "todos os navegadores" que isso não é bem verdade, e depende da versão, veja aqui: https://caniuse.com/#search=es6

Comment: @RicardoPontual correto, foi presunção minha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não faz muito sentido começar a aprender com soluções desatualizadas. Seria o mesmo que aprender engenharia com os conhecimentos que havia hà 50 anos. Um caso bem claro é o de `var`. Fazer um curso moderno a ensinar a usar `var` e não `let`/`const` não faz muito sentido. Parece-me errado. O mesmo se aplica para callbacks, Promises e async/await. Deixar de fora essas peças fundamentais do JavaScript moderno seria uma falha grande no curso.

Há ainda outras novidades que tornaram obsoletos métodos antigos como `.classList` e `dataset`, ... entre outros.

Acho que faz sentido um curso ter complexidade progressiva, começar com situações simples e aumentar a complexidade. Mas em relação à linguagem seria enganador "esconder" os progressos que tanto demoraram a chegar.

Eu diria que o que foi incluído na linguagem deve fazer parte do curso. Ao mesmo tempo deve referir-se a velocidade de implementação nos browsers ([como o Ricardo Pontual referiu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452114/d%c3%bavidas-sobre-ecmascript/452128#comment864479_452114)) e também referir futuros melhoramentos no estágio final do [processo da EcmaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposals).

Comment: Sergio, acho que sua resposta responde o porquê de não usar ES5, ES4 etc., mas faltou responder o porquê de usar ES6 e não ES7, ES8 etc.

Comment: @RafaelTavares Pq ES7, ES8, etc... ainda não tem suporte total dos navegadores, aliás, nem o ES6 o tem.

Answer (score -1):

**Objetivos do ES6:**

O TC39 focou em alguns objetivos no desenvolvimento do 
ES6:
Ser uma linguagem melhor para construir aplicações complexas
Resolver problemas antigos do JavaScript
Facilidade no desenvolvimento de libraries
Esses objetivos ficarão mais claros quando olharmos na prática as features do ES6.

**Novidades do ES6:**

Agora que já sabemos o que é o ES6 e como podemos usá-lo hoje mesmo com o Babel, podemos então ver as features que ele adicionará na linguagem e seus benefícios.

**E como o Sérgio já disse não faz sentido aprender algo desatualizado.**

**E acrecentando o que o @LeAndrade comentou outras versões posteriores possívelmente não tem suporte a todos os navegadores**

Comment: Se ES6 é a versão mais nova do JavaScript, o que são o ES7, ES8, ES9... conforme mencionados na pergunta?

Comment: Corrigi, muito obrigado pela crítica construtiva, não tinha notado :)